# What does Foundation use for syntax highlighting?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm building a blog using Foundation for the CSS and I need to be able to post code (php, js, and html mostly) within the posts without it executing. Right now I'm posting code within `<pre>` tags.

I noticed in the documentation for Foundation that their code examples have some styling, but I can't figure out if it's something that's included in the Foundation framework or if they're using something external.

You can see an example here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/navigation.php#btopCode

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are using a javascript library called Rainbows. Here is a link. http://craig.is/making/rainbows

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a syntax highlighter as a part of foundation. You might be interested in trying out [snippet.](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/)

Answer (score 0):

Foundation documentation use http://highlightjs.org/ highlighter with github css theme by [Vasily Polovnyov](http://code.google.com/p/srcsoft-spoiler/source/browse/trunk/highlight/github.css?r=11)